# jQuery AJAX $_POST is null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Help me to understand how AJAX works. I am trying to get `$_POST` in a PHP file, yet it is `null`. Please tell me where I went wrong?

```js
$('#pdfGenerator').on('submit', pdfEdit);

function pdfEdit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = [],
    pdfLists = [];
    
  $('.file-box .file-item').each(function(index, element) {
    pdfLists.push({
      'i': index,
      'pdf_id': $(element).find('textarea').attr('id'),
      'pdf_title': $(element).find('h6').text(),
      'pdf_add_text': $(element).find('textarea').val(),
    });
  });
  
  data.pdfLists = pdfLists;
  console.log(data);
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
```

https://codepen.io/alone69li/pen/mdrVbXW

Comment: Please share your PHP code. The `$_POST` superglobal itself will never be `NULL`.

Comment: Also, try removing `contentType: false,
        processData: false,`...these should not be necessary for sending some simple data.

Comment: contentType: false,
processData: false,
But not working

Comment: php file: 
$response['data'][] = json_decode($_POST['pdfLists']);

Comment: The post request is already empty in the request and does not reach the php file

Comment: That can't be the entire file. Again, please share `ajax.php` so we can help you.

Comment: Please use the "edit" button under your question to add more details and code, to show exactly what you're doing, and exactly what is and isn't in your $_POST variable. Do a `var_dump($_POST);` and show us the output.

Comment: Check the inspector if the browser is sending the request body. If it it's sending it okay, try to get the information this way: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: @AlexRuiz OP is not sending the data in JSON format, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To submit data to PHP via ajax, you need to have the processData tag set to true.
Please try changing

```
  $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        data:data,
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        },
```

to

```
  $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        data:data,
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: true,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        },
```